# React-bootstrap grid layout: why do rows overlap on screen resize?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a basic layout structure which consists of 2 rows:

- Row 1 has 2 columns
- Row 2 has 1 column

When possible both rows should expand in width and prevent vertical scroll of the page. However, when resizing I want to make the first row's columns stack vertically, with the column of the second row stacking below them.

Consider the following snippet:

```
import { Col, Container, Row, Table } from "react-bootstrap";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container fluid className="d-flex flex-column h-100">
      <Row style={{minHeight: 0}} className="flex-fill">
        <Col  lg={12} xl={9} className="h-100 overflow-auto bg-info">
          <Table responsive>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {[...Array(100)].map((x, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td>Row {i}</td>
                  <td>Row {i}</td>
                  <td>Row {i}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </Col>
        <Col
          lg={12}
          xl={3}
          className="h-100 bg-secondary p-5 text-center text-white fs-1"
        >
          Content
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row className="">
        <Col style={{backgroundColor: "rgb(255,0,0,0.4)"}} className="h-100 p-5 text-white fs-1">
          Other Content
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is also the `index.html` in case it matters:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="vh-100 vw-100" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body class="vh-100 vw-100">
    <div id="root" class="vh-100 vw-100"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This does not produce the expected result. It works great when they are expanded in width, but once I resize below the lg breakpoint, the "Content" column stacks beneath the table column as expected, but the "Other Content" column stays on top of it instead of moving further down.

Screensots for clarity:

[image: Before lg breakpoint]

[image: After lg breakpoint]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, It may resolve your issue.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container fluid className="d-flex flex-column h-100">
      <Row style={{minHeight: 0}} className="flex-fill">
        <Col  lg={9} xl={9} className="h-100`enter code here` overflow-auto bg-info">
          <Table responsive>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {[...Array(100)].map((x, i) => (
                <tr key={i}>
                  <td>Row {i}</td>
                  <td>Row {i}</td>
                  <td>Row {i}</td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </Table>
        </Col>
        <Col
          lg={3}
          xl={3}
          className="h-100 bg-secondary p-5 text-center text-white fs-1"
        >
          Content
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row className="">
        <Col style={{backgroundColor: "rgb(255,0,0,0.4)"}} className="h-100 p-5 text-white fs-1">
          Other Content
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with the editor toolbar so you can format your code properly. Also, take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: Some explanation would make this answer better. See [answer] for tips.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this did not solve it.  Not sure what to put in  @isherwoods `insert code here`.